# VS Code suggestions for PHP show everything, instead of class functions only

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I tried setting up VS Code for a legacy PHP project, to evaluate it against other IDEs.
My problem is with the **suggestions** I get, when I press `<an object>->Ctrl+Space`.
For example I want to get all suggestions (properties and functions) of a certain class. I am in the class and I type:

```
$this->(Ctrl+Space)
```

I get a large list of functions and constants, which are things I can use in PHP in general and not the functions and properties of the class I am in. After I installed the **[PHP Intelephense extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client)**, I get the class methods that I need in my suggestions, but still they are mixed with everything else and hard to find, unless I start typing the first letters of the function I need to access. To show you what I mean, this is what I get, when I type the following within a function of my class:

[image]

I don't think this is a matter of extension, because even if I disable all my extensions I still get the whole bunch of suggestions. ***How can I remove all unnecessary suggestions, or at least give priority to the class specific suggestions and see them on top of the list?***

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You must disable the vscode built-in PHP Language Features.

1. Click extensions.
2. In the search bar type `@builtin php`.
3. Click cog icon of PHP Language Features.
4. Click Disable.

[image: Extension UI - Disabling built-in PHP Language Features]

Answer (score 15):

I've been struggling with this for while too ...

You can just disable the basic PHP suggestions by setting php.suggest.basic to false in your settings.json file or use the settings UI at PHP > Suggest: Basic

With Intelephense installed everything works as expected now !

source : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php#_disable-builtin-php-support